# Remove an item if value is NaT from list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

How to remove a NaT value from list of dictionaries.

```
a = [{'subject':'Maths','name':'marcus','time':Timestamp('2020-08-31 11:26:28.230000')},
{'subject':'Maths','name':'paul','time':NaT}]
```

Final Output

```
a = [{'subject':'Maths','name':'marcus','time':Timestamp('2020-08-31 11:26:28.230000')},
{'subject':'Maths','name':'paul'}]
```

DataType of `time` key if value is `NaT` is `pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType`

Answer (score 1):

Use nested list with dict comprehension with [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) filter:

```
b = [{k:v for k, v in d.items() if pd.notna(v)} for d in a]
print (b)
[{'subject': 'Maths', 'name': 'marcus', 'time': Timestamp('2020-08-31 11:26:28.230000')},
 {'subject': 'Maths', 'name': 'paul'}]
```